# Traceback little prob

Tags: python

I got that error when i use "swtichbot bonuschanger on game"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ui.py", line 1506, in OnToggleDown

File "switchbot.py", line 115, in Activate

AttributeError
'int' object has no attribute 'gameWindow'

ui.py

```
def OnToggleDown(self):
        if self.eventDown:
            self.eventDown()  #--Line 1506
```

swtichbot.py

```
def Activate(self):
    self.sub_parent.resetSwitch()
    self.Status_new.SetColor(COLOR_ACTIVE)
    self.sub_parent.StatusBar.SetColor(COLOR_ACTIVE)
    self.sub_parent.StatusText.SetText("Activ")
    self.Starter.SetText("Switcher slot ("+str(self.index+1)+")")
    self.sub_parent.boni_active = 1
    if self.parentWindow.parentWindow.gameWindow != None: #--line 115
        self.sub_parent.blockBar.swib_normal.SetColor(COLOR_ACTIVE)
pass
```

how can i edit them to don't get this error anymore? just a little help i'm pretty newbie :D

Comment: What is `self.parentWindow.parentWindow`? Parent window has an element that is another parent window?

Comment: "swtichbot bonuschanger on game" - excuse me? What's that? A library?

Comment: sry guys im just a beginner i try to do something without errors ..but i need to learn ..

Comment: i think is another parent to dezactivate

Comment: Okay, you have to give us more. We need a [mcve]. Specifically we need to know the class implementation and what library you are using, the include directive.

Comment: The error is saying that this object `self.parentWindow.parentWindow` is an integer, so it doesn't have that attribute. I think that if you change it to this `self.parentWindow` it might work, but that's just a guess based on the error.

Comment: Just one additional note: Please consider [changing the title of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). "Traceback little prob" doesn't provide any useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed this line

```
if self.parentWindow.parentWindow.gameWindow != None: #--line 115
```

with this one

```
if self.sub_parent.parentWindow.parentWindow.gameWindow != None:
```

thanks a lot for your time , you the best !!!